# Slim REST API Delete record from db and an image file

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I'm a beginner with the Slim framework, I'm using it as a Rest Backend for my mobile application. I'm able to do CRUD operations in the database, but when deleting a record I'm not able to delete the linked image (I'm storing the path of the image in the database).

I tried several ways after searching the internet but nothing worked as I intended - everything gave me an error. Can anyone please help me find my problem?

index.php

```
$app->delete('/deleteData/:id', 'authenticate', function($id) use($app) {
            $db = new DbHandler();
            $response = array();
            $result = $db->deleteData($id);
            if ($result) {
                // task deleted successfully
                $response["error"] = "false";
                $response["message"] = "Data deleted succesfully";
            } else {
                // task failed to delete
                $response["error"] = "true";
                $response["message"] = "Data failed to delete. Please try again!";
            }
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

DBHandler.php

```
public function deleteData($id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM task WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_affected_rows > 0;
    }
```

Currently, I am able to delete records from the db, but I cannot delete the image from the uploads folder.

Comment: How do you identify the file you want to delete?  You say you have tried things, but get errors.  Perhaps if you show what you have tried along with the errors, it may be able to solve your problem.

Comment: i have file name in table .

Comment: 1. Read the record to fetch the filename, 2. delete the file, 3. delete the record by id.